# Django - Pass variable to serializer which gets used in calculating a serializers.SerializerMethodField?

Tags: python, django, serialization

So I have this serializer that adds an attribute. Let's say I want to serialize `Post` data, which is like a post on Facebook or Twitter. When I serialize it lets say I want to pass a variable to the serializer `region`, because I use that variable to calculate an attribute in the Serializer that I want. So for example I'd like to do something like `PostSerializer(post_object, region='Italy')` and it'll use `region='Italy'` for calculating an attribute which is a `serializers.SerializerMethodField`. **How can I pass a variable to my serializer that is used to calculae a `serializers.SerializerMethodField()`?**

`serializer.py`

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    post_count_from_region = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('author', 'body', 'created', 'updated_at', 'post_count_from_region')

    def get_post_count_from_region(self, post_obj, region:str):
        return Post.objects.filter(region=region).count()
```

So for a more explicit example of what this use case looks like is:

`view.py`

```
def get_full_post_data_by_uuid(request, post_uuid, region: str):
    post_obj = Post.objects.get(pk=post_uuid)
    return Response(PostSerializer(post_obj, region=region).data, status=200)
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is what `context` is for in Serializers on Django. `context` takes in a dictionary so you can do.

```
PostSerializer(post_object, context={'region':'Italy'})
```

then under serializer

```
def get_post_count_from_region(self, post_obj):
    region = self.context.get('region', <default value>)
    return Post.objects.filter(region=region).count()
```